# delete duplicate user_id from table except 5 latest data with date

Tags: php, mysql

this is the image where I need to delete the duplicate the old user_id by date but need to keel the latest 5 data of the user_id

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you signed up today, to get a better idea of what types of questions you can ask, and what's off-topic. This looks like a broad question without any code/attempt from your side. Share code snippet or more information.

Answer (score 0):

delete FROM table_name where id not in (select id from table_name order by datee asc limit 5);

Comment: I mean to say: each user_id keep at most 5 latest data by date and delete old data of that user_id. like user_id=10  keeps 5 latest data by date and other user_id also and so on